# Having problems trying to figure how to get the total for items that I loop through

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't seem to figure how to get the total of the items I am looping through when I do it this way it just shows me the price like 6 56 6 for 3 items. I need it to show me the total for all three items so with this example it should show me total of 68  Any help would be appreciated to understanding how to do this.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?> Thank you!</h2></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Your order was successfully sent. Your Transaction ID number is <b><?php echo $tr_id; ?></b> </h3>

    <p>
        <table class="table table-hovered">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>               
<?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM customer_order WHERE uid='$uid' and tr_id='$tr_id'  order by id desc";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query))
    {


                   echo "\t<tr><td>".$row['p_name']."</td><td>".$row['p_qty']."</td><td>".$row['p_price']."</td></tr>\n";

                  echo $row['p_qty'] * $row['p_price'] ;
    }

    ?>
    </table>

  </p>
                    <a href="profile.php" class='btn btn-success btn-lg'>Back to Supplies</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You probably need a `SUM()` aggregate function and a `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one variable `$total` in this case. Keep it's starting value zero. And at every interval just add the price for each product. Hope this will work for you.

```
$total = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query))
    {
            echo "\t<tr><td>".$row['p_name']."</td><td>".$row['p_qty']."</td><td>".$row['p_price']."</td></tr>\n";
            echo $row['p_qty'] * $row['p_price'] ;
            $total = $total + $row['p_qty'] * $row['p_price'];
    }
    echo "Total Price = ".$total;
```

Comment: Your answer Nikhil is correct I can accept it in 4 min

Answer (score 0):

Where you are computing values, wrap your values with floatval and round.  Be aware that if you have formatting characters with your numeric values, you need to remove those first.

e.g.
echo round( floatval($row[]) * floatval($row[]) , 2 );